# how to change www to something else in Django urls?

Tags: python, django, url, nginx, django-urls

I've created a rest API for my Django app but how I go to api.website.com rather than something like www.website.com/api

Btw I'm using nginx if that has to do anything with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your nginx configuration add something like this. This passes all requests on `api.website.com` to your gunicorn socket -> your django app.

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name api.website.com;

    location ~ ^/api(.*)$ {
      try_files $uri $1 /$1;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_pass http://gunicorn_socket/;
    }
}
```